# background-position not working if #color instead of image

Tags: css, background-position

```
background:transparent url(../img/fondo_footer.png) repeat-x scroll;
background-position: 0px 140px;
```

This way the background is vertically moved

---

```
background:#01244e;
background-position: 0px 140px;
```

this way, is not

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

background-position only applies to images according to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html

So if you supply a color value, it will apply to the whole element.

Comment: so my only chance here is to make an image with that color?

Comment: I assume that you want some gradient background. In this case, see how it does jQuery UI for example. They use small sample of the backgroud(vertical or horizontal) line to show the gradient. Then they change the bg position that allows to move over the gradient.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make a sense. Since you're setting the background color, it doesn't matter what position do you set, because the color everywhere the same. If you set the image, then the position means what part of image you're going to show.